# How to update a declarative SQLAlchemy model using a dictionary data while running validators

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The question really is how to update a SQLAlchemy declarative model so that it runs the validators. In my case using setters like `User.name = name` is not really an option.

Below is a runnable example of what I mean

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

some_engine = create_engine('sqlite://')
Session = sessionmaker(bind=some_engine)
session = Session()


Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    @validates('name')
    def validate_name(self, key, value):
        if value != 'asd':
            raise ValueError('not asd')
        return value

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=some_engine)

user = User(id=1, name='qwe')
# >>> ValueError: not asd
user = User(id=1, name='asd')

session.add(user)
session.commit()

session.query(User).filter(User.id=1).update({'name': 'qwe'})
session.query(User).filter(User.id==1)[0].name
# >>> 'qwe'
```

Comment: The validates decorator is a convenience function on top of [AttributeEvents](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents). As such it'll not function with bulk updates. Mapper events such as before update will not fire on bulk updates either. There's a warning about bulk updates in the docs: "The `Query.update()` method is a “bulk” operation, which **bypasses ORM unit-of-work automation in favor of greater performance**. Please read all caveats and warnings below." You could add CHECK constraints at DB level for enforcing "not asd".

Comment: Defining CHECK constraints in SQLAlchemy: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#check-constraint

Comment: I have to admit the disclaimer of "bypassing unit-of-work automation" tells me nothing, unfortunately SQLAlchemy docs are really messy and sucky :(

Comment: In that case you should refresh your [session basics](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html), for example.

Comment: Sure, but that still doesn't answer the question. And the docs could do a lot better job just saying "all validations are skipped" etc

Comment: The answer in case of bulk operations (`Query.update()`, the different bulk operations `Session` has, Core inserts/updates) is to have a CHECK constraint at DB level.

Comment: And the question is at it's core "how to update" meaning, what if any methods for updating there are other than bulk updates which would take validations into account. And preferably be callable with a dict off-the-shelf

Answer (score 4):

You could add a mixin to your models that provides a rather simple update method that just uses `setattr()` to set attributes of an instance.

```
class UpdateMixin:
    """
    Add a simple update() method to instances that accepts
    a dictionary of updates.
    """
    def update(self, values):
        for k, v in values.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

User class would then be defined as

```
class User(UpdateMixin, Base):
    ...
```

And to update a **single instance** from a given dictionary you could for example run

```
session.query(User).get(1).update({ 'name': 'qwe' })
# or since you have the user instance from before
user.update({ 'name': 'qwe' })
```

Note the use of [`Query.get()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.get). If there is no user with the given id, it will return None and trying to call the method update on it will raise. Another caveat is that if you do not rollback if any exceptions are raised, you cannot predict what, if any, updates took place (were added to the session) because a dictionary has no ordering. So always rollback on any errors.

I'd also recommend actually naming the method `updateSelf` or some such to prevent risk of confusing it with `Query.update()`.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is not to use query.update when you want model level constraints.  It's exactly for the times when performance is more important than enforcing those sorts of model level constraints.  Other answers have  provided specifics on solutions, but the fundamental answer is that Query.update is not intended to enforce python-level constraints.
General categories of solutions are:

- Use some session-level method and `Query.get` or a loop on `Query.filter.all`
- Check constraints
- Triggers and stored procedures